# Json output with none, one or many dictionaries in a tubple - best way to manipulate? (Bitstamp transaction list)

Tags: python, json, api

Hy, still a python beginner, I am looking for help pointing me in the right direction:
I am trying to build sort of a database of api answers from bitstamp listing the transactions on bitstamp.

The api-call gives all transactions in a time frame, output is json.
After processing the api output with json.loads() output can be

1. no transaction: `[]`
2. one transaction: `{'key':'value',....}`
3. many transactions:  `{'key':'value',....} {'key':'value',....} {'key':'value',....}`

As I understand this:

1. ok: `if x=='[]':return`
2. ok: `for key in x: print(x[key])`
3. seems to be a tuple. dont know how to deal with, I would like to make as many dictionarys out of the transactions-tuple as there are. So sort of
   for every tuple make `dict[x]` with tuple in it.

I know some mysql, in the end I want to have a table with one transaction per line, sorted chronologically, so i can build a chart of the transaction prices or some sort of 2-dimensional array, that i can acces by `array[x][y]`.

I dont aks for a complete solution, just a short idea how it could/should be done, so I can start my way through the tutorials :)

p.s.: reason for json.load is, that the native output is like `[{key:value, ..} {key:value,...}]`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all transactions contain the same structure, it is perfectly fine to use a `for item in json_tuple` to deal with the transactions.

It all really depends on what you want to do with the data set.

Comment: Yes, got that, so i get as many single {} as there are dictionaries in the tuple. How can I assign these dictionaries to variable names? a1={} a2={} where a1 goes til a[x], x=number of dicts in tuple..

Answer (score 0):

I would just loop through all the transactions returned and insert them into your database. The easiest scenario is that each transaction has the same keys, but you can handle variable keys fairly easily as well. To work with mysql in python I would recommend `MySQLdb`, you can find a good tutorial [here](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/).

```
for transaction in output:
    # INSERT into TABLE VALUES(...,...,...)
```

This loop has the added advantage of handling cases where no output is returned (the loop isn't run).

Comment: good point! so i could skip all python-dictionary stuff and just feed it into mysql, like that :)

Comment: I would still use `json.loads()` to load the json string into python objects. If you don't do that, you will essentially be working with strings, which can cause much more headache than it's worth.